# Why not just Disapparate when the Snatchers arrive?

Tags: harry-potter

I'm currently reading *Deathly Hallows*.  Once Voldemort's name has been Tabboo'd, it summons the Death Eaters, as well as breaking protective charms on an area (case and point, Harry's Tent).

When it is uttered, Death Eaters appear outside the tent in which Hermione, Harry and Ron are hiding.

Since the only requirement for Apparition appears to be a wand (no verbal cue to alert the Death Eaters) and Disapparating can be done extremely quickly (for example: Mundungus Fletcher  in Hogsmeade, Dobby's death) - why don't the group just get gone and escape before they are taken to Malfoy Manor?

Comment: I always think the same thing when I read that passage. They have plenty of time to do it. I've had to accept that Rowling either didn't think this through properly or imagined that the taboo also somehow automagically set up an anti-Apparition perimeter around the area where the taboo word was spoken, like a miniature Hogwarts or (in _Deathly Hallows_) Hogsmeade or Ministry of Magic. I've absolutely no evidence for this, though, and even if it were true, I don't see how the trio could have known about it—and they don't even _try_ to Disapparate.

Comment: I assumed that the protective enchantments Hermione cast prevented apparation - note that when Ron storms off he leaves the tent and walks off into the darkness, rather than disapparate in the boundary of the camp. It would make sense that they don't want someone just appearing in the tent!

Answer (score 5):

Speculative, but my guess is that Hermione's protective enchantments prevent Apparation/Disaparation within the bounds of the camp.

We know such spells are possible (*Honestly*, haven't you read *Hogwarts: A History*?) and it makes sense that the trio wouldn't want any unexpected visitors in the camp. It would also explain why the Snatchers don't just Apparate into the tent with them! Furthermore, note that when Ron storms off he leaves the tent and walks off into the darkness before Disaparating, rather than Disapparate in the boundary of the camp.

> “Ron, no—please—come back, come back!”  She was impeded by her own
>   Shield Charm; by the time she had removed it he had already stormed
>   into the night. Harry stood quite still and silent, listening to her
>   sobbing and calling Ron’s name amongst the trees.  After a few minutes
>   she returned, her sopping hair plastered to her face.  “He’s g-g-gone!
>   Disapparated!”

I haven't had time to check the books though, so if there are any instances of them Apparating within the camp then obviously this theory is wrong, but as far as I remember they never do.

Comment: Since you posted your answer both here and on the duplicate question, I’ll repeat my comment, too: Except the whole point of the Taboo is that it breaks protective enchantments like that. It was impossible to Apparate or Disapparate before Harry said Voldemort’s name, but the moment he said it, it became possible. That’s why the Snatchers could find them in the first place.